# IE8 doesn't respect CSS rule overriding

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, overriding, css-selectors

I have spent the last 2 hours on this and I have no idea what's wrong and how to fix it.

Let's assume the following HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>IE8 test</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <p>First line - bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>
        <p>Second line - bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>
        <p class="red last">Third line - bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

#myDiv {
    border: 1px solid green;
}

#myDiv p {
    text-align: center;
}

#myDiv p:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}

#myDiv p.last, #myDiv p:last-child { /* THIS IS WHAT DOESN'T WORK IN IE8 */
    text-align: right;
}

.red {
    color: red;
}
```

Obviously, this should center all the text in the div, but then put the first line to the left and the last line to the right. It works flawlessly in newer browsers but IE8 fails (oh what a surprise...).

Seems like it is not respecting `#myDiv p.last, #myDiv p:last-child`. I added `class="last"` as IE8 doesn't know `last-child` but anyway, the `text-align:center` is simply NOT overriden with `text-align:right`. Anybody has an idea how to fix it? I really need to get this working in IE8. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @raina77ow Gosh, you are right, I cannot believe I wasted so much time with this! Thanks a lot, please add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should leave just `#myDiv p.last` in the selector. As `:last-child` selector expression is not recognized by IE8, it just ignores the whole rule (as potentially invalid).

It's a general rule of thumb (prescribed by [**the standard**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#Conformance)): browser can't understand a selector => browser ignores it (along with the corresponding rule).

Answer (score 0):

:last-child is not supported in IE8.  See here: http://caniuse.com/#search=last-child

Comment: That was mentioned in the question (=I know that). What I didn't know is that all the rule is ignored by IE in case last-child is used.

Comment: oops. sorry for that, @Fygo - Should have completely read the last sentance you added there before hauling off to answer.  Glad you got it worked out.